# Can I write relative clauses modifying whole sentences without "which"?

Tags: relative-clauses

Can I write relative clauses modifying whole sentences without "which"? Is it grammatically correct?

> Example 1:
>
> My friends didn't come to the reunion, **which infuriated me.**
>   =>
>   My friends didn't come to the reunion, **infuriating me.**
>
> Example 2:
>
> The storm dumped heavy downpours in this town, **which caused many injuries.**
>   =>
>   The storm dumped heavy downpours in this town, **causing many injuries.**

Comment: ***Certainly.***

Comment: No: "Infuriating me" and "causing many injuries" are not a relative clauses. They are non-finite clauses functioning as resultative adjuncts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versions are grammatical, but the first one now sounds like *your **friends*** (not the described fact: 'not coming to the reunion') literally '***infuriated*** you'. It can be rewritten like this:

> My friends didn't come to the reunion, *and that* infuriated me.

In your second sentence, the sense is *just slightly* modified (technically, now it '*caused injuries while dumping heavy downpours*' vs '*caused injuries, as a final result*'). It can also be written like this: *... **and that** caused many injuries*.

Answer (score 1):

> *My friends didn't come to the reunion,* [*infuriating me*].
>
> *The storm dumped heavy downpours in this town,* [*causing many injuries*].

No: the bracketed elements are not relative clauses, though they are modifiers. The absence of a relative pronoun marks them as non-finite clauses functioning as resultative adjuncts in clause structure.

Note that non-defining relative clauses like your ones with "which" are not modifiers, but supplements, i.e. loosely attached expressions set off by punctuation and providing supplementary non-integrated content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what you said, the implication is that the form "infuriating me" is not derived from the form "which infuriated me"??

Comment: @vincentlin Correct: it's a different construction.